# Wifi card monitor mode

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I'm on Antergos linux, 4.9.73-1-lts x86_64. I've bought a usb wi-fi adapter tp-link tl-wn722n and can't set it up on my laptop. I also have MT7630e wi-fi card inside. Are the ways to enter the monitor mode on the second card the same? What info/logs should I post?

```
[root@OrpheusPlanet starorpheus]# iwconfig
 wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Mamus"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: C0:25:E9:B1:A1:92   
           Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=56 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:13  Invalid misc:74   Missed beacon:0

 wlp0s20u1  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"       ; this one is external
           Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
           Sensitivity:0/0  
           Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Encryption key:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**BUT**

```
[root@OrpheusPlanet starorpheus]# iw dev
 phy#0
      Interface wlp3s0f0
           ifindex 3
           wdev 0x1
           addr ec:0e:c4:29:80:d9
           type managed
           channel 4 (2427 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
           txpower 20.00 dBm
```

**And**

```
 [root@OrpheusPlanet starorpheus]# iw wlp0s20u1 set monitor control
 command failed: No such device (-19)
```

So, everything looks like I **have** an installed wi-fi driver to this card (I can connect to networks), but it doesn't support monitor mode. 
Am I right? How can I check that?

Comment: What are you using to put it into monitor/promiscuous mode? I use airmon-ng. I'm not familiar with this distro. You may have to add a repository for it. Do a apt-get install, or whatever your distro uses to install packages.

Comment: The external card not showing up in `iw dev` while it does in `iwconfig` is bad. I suspect outdated drivers which don't use the modern API. Please update to the newest kernel of your distro. After that, edit question with the new lines in `dmesg` that appear when you plug in the adapter (type `dmesg` before and remember last line, or look at timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your device.
The TLWN722N V2 native driver won't support monitor mode. Unless you install a custom driver provided by Mfruba [Link](https://github.com/mfruba/kernel/tree/master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink)